# Rearrange JSON data into compatible format using .map, .filter, .reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm very new with JavaScript so bear with me. I've got given unchangeable JSON data in the form of:

```
export const JSON = [
        {
            fruit: "Banana",
            name: "Tony",
            tree: {
            type: [
                {
                   number: 123,
                   desc: {
                      color: "yellow"
                   }
                }
            ]
            }
        }
]
```

And I will need to rearrange it into (where I only have fruit, number and color as the types):

```
export const formatted = [
    {fruit: "banana", number: 123, color: "yellow"}
];
```

Any suggestions on how I would do this in JS React?

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods you mention? What happened? SO isn't a code-writing service; where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` on the array and for each element return a new object that just contains the data you are interested in.

**Example**

```js
const data = [
  {
    fruit: "Banana",
    name: "Tony",
    tree: {
      type: [
        {
          number: 123,
          desc: {
            color: "yellow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

const result = data.map(obj => ({
  fruit: obj.fruit,
  number: obj.tree.type[0].number,
  color: obj.tree.type[0].desc.color,
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a simple call to **[`Array#map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, this is how should be your code:

```
const res = json.map(x => {
  return {
    "fruit": x.fruit,
    "number": x.tree.type[0].number,
    "color": x.tree.type[0].desc.color
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const json = [{
  fruit: "Banana",
  name: "Tony",
  tree: {
    type: [{
      number: 123,
      desc: {
        color: "yellow"
      }
    }]
  }
}];


const res = json.map(x => {
  return {
    "fruit": x.fruit,
    "number": x.tree.type[0].number,
    "color": x.tree.type[0].desc.color
  }
});
console.log(res);
```